# How to reconstruct conversations or group emails?

Tags: email, outlook, pst, java-libpst

I am having a PST files which contains the email history of a user. The task is to read this PST file and reconstruct the email history to display it in a client. This includes the correctly displaying of conversations as you know it from Email clients:

```
Meeting at 8:00               07:34 am
  AW: Meeting at 8:00         09:12 am
    AW: AW: Meeting at 8:00   13:45 pm
[Jenkins Build] Success       11:54 am
  [Jenkins Build] Failed      12:13 pm
    [Jenkins Build] Success   01:12 pm
[Jenkins Build] Success       10:34 am
  [Jenkins Build] Failed      12:12 pm
    [Jenkins Build] Success   05:12 pm
```

However, I don't know how I could do this reliably.

I am using [java-libpst](https://github.com/rjohnsondev/java-libpst) (see [Official Documentation](http://rjohnsondev.github.io/java-libpst/overview-summary.html)) which provides a [PSTMessage](http://rjohnsondev.github.io/java-libpst/com/pff/PSTMessage.html) object. There is a method `getConversationId()` but that appears to be just a string of the original subject of that message which means that there might be duplicates (e.g. `[Jenkins Build]*`).

So, I am not sure how Outlook is able to reconstruct conversations and whether this is trivial but if there is actually a simple method to do this which I am just overlooking I'd be happy if somebody would let me know - otherwise this will end up in me parsing a ton of subject fields, parsing them and trying to match emails by their subject with the danger of missing different conversations which just have the same subject coincidentally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to construct the conversations yourself.  You might find the source code referenced on this page about [the Netscape Mail message threading algorithm](https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) helpful.

I copied the source code to Github.  Here's [the email `Threader.java` file](https://github.com/carlgieringer/mozilla-grendel/blob/master/grendel/view/Threader.java).

Here is someone offering [an explanation of how Gmail constructs conversations](https://support.cloudhq.net/how-does-gmail-decide-to-group-emails-into-conversations/)  My gist is:

1. Emails coming after an email with an equivalent subject, from any of the participants in any previous email, are part of the same conversation.
2. The `in-reply-to` email field can create participants to an email conversation even if they weren't an explicit participant.

Where:

`equivalent subject` means either an identical subject, or a subject that would result replying or forwarding.  I.e. "FW: X", "RE: X", "Fwd: X", etc.

`explicit participants in an email`: the sender or any email appearing in a TO: or CC: field.  (Maybe a BCC: field too...)

`participants in an email`: explicit participants in an email or anyone who has sent a later email using the `in-reply-to` field.

`participants in any previous email`: the distinct emails that are participants in email with an earlier send date having equivalent subject to a current email.

Here's another [exposition of email fields relevant to email threading](https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html).  What I took from this is that the `References` header should also be consulted in addition to the `in-reply-to` header, and that it is more reliable.  (Maybe, if present, it should supercede the `in-reply-to` header.